# Gitlab and Apache can't handle ~20mb push

Tags: git, apache, gitlab

I've setup my server running appache and Gitlab 7.3.1. It has been working fine, however once I tried to push a commit which was larger then normal (18mb) it can't handle it. What I get is this

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 502
fatal: The remote end hungup unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end  hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I really don't know what is going on. I think it has something to do with Apache and it acting as a proxy. I'm running it over HTTPS. I've used the configuration located [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-ssl-apache2.4.conf) and it is identical except for paths needed for my server and URIS. I've also tried some other things, such as making sure the body request size is 0 (meaning unlimited) and still no luck.

When I go and have a look at my apache logs this is what is spat out:

```
[Mon Oct 20 02:34:20.941960 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 4740] (32)Broken pipe: [client    60.225.212.163:58480] AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Oct 20 02:34:20.942010 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 4740] [client 60.225.212.163:58480] AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) from 60.225.212.163 ()
```

Can anyone help me. I've spent two days on this now and still now luck!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

Even though I had increased the timeout in the `/home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb` to 60 it still wasn't enough time.

I increased the time limit to 300 seconds (5 mins) and low and behold it ticked over and worked. What a pain. If anyone else is using Gitlab and wants to upload large files make sure your timeout is massive as this is only ~20mb.